# Routing Not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

In Global.asax file i used below code

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(
    "MySampleRouter", 
    "MyData/NewsTitle/{NewsTitledef}", 
    "~/NewsDetails.aspx");
```

Then redirecting page ,

```
href="MyData/NewsTitle/<%# Eval("Title")%>
```

But while debugging,getting an error like

> "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has
>   been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: do you have a 'NewsDetails.aspx' webform residing in the root of your MVC website?

Comment: The two forms are in same folder..Now i solved the issue by changing path